# Commands to switch kubectl and gcloud back and forth between two totally separate projects

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, kubectl

**Edit/Update**: I should have noted, that for both of these clients/projects, I do have 2 separate Gmail accounts (`user1@client1.example.com` and `user2@client2.example.com`).

---

I am a freelancer that is new to K8s and GCP. I happen to be on two separate projects that *just* started using both of these technologies around the same time, and I am trying to manage clusters and projects from both of these clients from the same laptop. I want to be able to switch back and forth between each client and their respective K8s/GCP project and I'm looking for a list of all the kubectl and gcloud commands for doing this back and forth switchback.

So to reiterate:

- Client #1

  - project ABC
- Client #2

  - project DEF

Locally when I run `kubectl config get-clusters` I see:

```
docker-desktop
gke_client-1-proj-abc-dev
gke_client-2-proj-def-dev
minikube
```

Where `gke_client-1-proj-abc-dev` is Client #1 (project ABC)'s dev environment K8s cluster, and where `gke_client-2-proj-def-dev` is Client #2 (project DEF)'s dev K8s cluster.

However when I run:

```
gcloud projects list             
PROJECT_ID              NAME                     PROJECT_NUMBER
client-1-proj-abc       Client 1 Proj ABC Local  12345 (omitting actual project #s for brevity)
client-1-proj-abc-dev   Client 1 Proj ABC Dev    23456
client-1-proj-abc-qa    Client 1 Proj ABC QA     34567
```

So it appears the `kubectl` is correctly "connected" to both client projects, but `gcloud` is only logged-in/authenticated/connected to Client #1 and not Client #2.

Either way, I'm looking for the exact commands I can use so that:

- when I'm "connected to" (pointing at) Client #1, all `gcloud` and `kubectl` commands are scoped to them and their project; and
- when I'm "connected to" (pointing at) Client #2, all `gcloud` and `kubectl` commands are scoped to them and their project; and
- there's an easy way for me to tell which client/project/cluster I'm "connected to" so that I don't inadvertently run `kubectl` and `gcloud` commands *intended* for one client, but actually muck up the clusters of another

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is understandable that you want to be diligent in keeping these clusters distinct. Whichever solution you choose, you will need to remain diligent. This is because, platform providers want to (maintain security) while reducing "friction" and so this is a common challenge for developers.

> **NOTE** I won't cover this but a complementary approach is for you to configure e.g. bash to change e.g. color settings based on configs. So, for example, you could configure bash to change your terminal's background to green for one customer and blue for another.

By default, Kubernetes stores its cluster configuration in a YAML file (on Linux) in `${HOME}/.kube/config`. You can open this file and see its structure. It contains `clusters`, `contexts` (more later), `users` and metadata. `contexts` provide a tuple that binds one `cluster`, to one `user` (and sometimes to one `namespace`). There's usually a `current-context` that points to the... current (in use)... `context` settings.

For Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), `user` entries leverage `gcloud` (Google's CLI for Cloud Platform) to obtain an `access-token` (`token-key`) that is used to authenticate to the GKE cluster:

```
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: [[redacted]]
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: path/to/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry: "2022-02-22T22:22:22Z"
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
```

Why all the preamble?

(I've not tried this but, given the above) If you have different Google accounts (e.g. `user@company1.com` and `user@company2.com` for each customer, the `access-token` for one customer's cluster **won't** permit you to access the other cluster. So this provides the strongest separation.

If you have a single Google account, you will need to be somewhat diligent in switching between the `contexts` that represent each of the clusters. When you were initially authenticated to each cluster (possibly with `gcloud container clusters get-credentials`, entries were written to `${HOME}/.kube/config` for both of the clusters and contexts should have been created too.

It's easiest to look at the file to see what's what. But (!) there should be at least 2 distinct `contexts` and their entries should marry to entries in `clusters` and `users`.

You can then simply:

```sh
kubectl use-context client-1
kubectl use-context client-2
```

You can *explicitly* specify the `--context` on any `kubectl` command too though this may become tiresome:

```sh
kubectl get deployments \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
--context=${CONTEXT}
```

You can create your own (user-defined) contexts too but you'll need to know the name of your clusters and users:

```sh
# Use a new name
kubectl config get-contexts

# Use one of each of these values
kubectl config get-clusters
kubectl config get-users
```

Then:

```sh
CLUSTER="..." # One of the above results
USER="..."    # One of the above results

NAMESPACE="..." # If you wish to use a specific cluster's namespace

kubectl config set-context ${CONTEXT} \
--cluster=${CLUSTER} \
--user=${USER} \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

Will create the following entry in your `${HOME}/.kube/config`:

```
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: ${CLUSTER}
    namespace: ${NAMESPACE} # This is optional
    user: ${USER}
  name: ${CONTEXT}
```

And you could then:

```sh
kubectl config use-context ${CONTEXT}
Switched to context "${CONTEXT}".
```

But, unless you query the config using `kubectl config current-context`, you won't have a visual clue as to which `context` you're using (unless you do some bash magic as noted above).

I blogged about this a long time ago. Hopefully it helps [Kubernetes Engine: `kubectl config`](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-engine-kubectl-config-b6270d2b656c)

Comment: Thanks so much @DazWilkin (+1) -- I should have mentioned this, **yes** I do have 2 distinct emails/gmails, one for each client. And thank you for the explanation of the contexts, that answers a lot of other ancillary questions I've always had. The only thing I'm concerned about is that when I ran `gcloud projects list` none of my Client #2 projects showed up in the results. Is that because I'm not authenticated with them (because the "context" is currently pointing at Client #1 resources)? Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm pleased to hear that it helped. Yes, you will only see Google Cloud Platform projects listed for which the currently authenticated user (!) has permissions. You can see which `gcloud` users you have authenticated using `gcloud auth list`. Note that only one is `*` (active). You can switch between authenticated `gcloud` users, using `gcloud config set account ${EMAIL}` (yes, `gcloud config`. Note `gcloud` has its own configurations (`gcloud config list`) too but I'd discourage using them.