# CLI command ordering for toggling between two GKE/kubectl accounts w/ two emails

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, kubectl

Several weeks ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71224960/commands-to-switch-kubectl-and-gcloud-back-and-forth-between-two-totally-separat) and received a very helpful answer. The gist of that question was: "*how do I switch back and forth between two different K8s/GCP accounts on the same machine?*" I have 2 different K8s projects with 2 different emails (gmails) that live on 2 different GKE clusters in 2 different GCP accounts. And I wanted to know how to switch back and forth between them so that when I run `kubectl` and `gcloud` commands, I don't inadvertently apply them to the wrong project/account.

The answer was to basically leverage `kubectl config set-context` along with a script.

This question (today) is an extenuation of that question, a "Part 2" so to speak.

---

I am confused about the *order* in which I:

- Set the K8s context (again via `kubectl config set-context ...`); and
- Run `gcloud init`; and
- Run `gcloud auth`; and
- Can safely run `kubectl` and `gcloud` commands and be sure that I am hitting the right GKE cluster

My *understanding* is that `gcloud init` only has to be ran once to initialize the `gcloud` console on your system. Which I have already done.

So my *thinking* here is that I could be able to do the following:

```
# 1. switch K8s context to Project 1
kubectl config set-context <context for GKE project 1>

# 2. authenticate w/ GCP so that now gcloud commands will only hit the GCP
# resources associated with Project 1 (and GCP Account 1)
gcloud auth

# 3. run a bunch of kubectl and gcloud commands for Project/GCP Account 1

# 4. switch K8s context to Project 2
kubectl config set-context <context for GKE project 2>

# 5. authenticate w/ GCP so that now gcloud commands will only hit the GCP
# resources associated with Project 2 (and GCP Account 2)
gcloud auth

# 6. run a bunch of kubectl and gcloud commands for Project/GCP Account 2
```

**Is my understanding here correct or is it more involved/complicated than this (and if so, why)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume familiarity with the earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71225494/609290)

#### `gcloud`

[`gcloud init`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/init) need only be run once per machine and only again if you really want to re-`init`'ialize the CLI (`gcloud`).

[`gcloud auth login ${ACCOUNT}`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) authenticates a (Google) (user or service) account and persists (on Linux by default in `${HOME}/.config/gcloud`) and renews the credentials.

[`gcloud auth list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/list) lists the accounts that have been `gcloud auth login`. The results show which account is being used by default (`ACTIVE` with `*`).

Somewhat inconveniently, one way to switch between the currently `ACTIVE` account is to change `gcloud` **global** (every instance on the machine) configuration using [`gcloud config set account ${ACCOUNT}`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set).

#### `kubectl`

To facilitate using previously authenticated (i.e. `gcloud auth login ${ACCOUNT}`) credentials with Kubernetes Engine, Google provides the command [`gcloud container clusters get-credentials`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials). This uses the currently `ACTIVE` `gcloud` account to create a `kubectl` context that joins a Kubernetes Cluster with a *User* and possibly with a Kubernetes Namespace too. `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` makes changes to `kubectl` config (on Linux by default in `${HOME}/.kube/config`).

What is a *User*? See [Users in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#users-in-kubernetes). Kubernetes Engine (via `kubectl`) wants (OpenID Connect) [Tokens](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#openid-connect-tokens). And, conveniently, `gcloud` can provide these tokens for us.

How? Per previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71225494/609290)

```
user:
  auth-provider:
    config:
      access-token: [[redacted]]
      cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
      cmd-path: path/to/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
      expiry: "2022-02-22T22:22:22Z"
      expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
      token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
    name: gcp
```

`kubectl` uses the configuration file to invoke `gcloud config config-helper --format=json` and extracts the `access_token` and `token_expiry` from the result. GKE can then use the `access_token` to authenticate the user. And, if necessary can renew the token using Google's token endpoint after expiry (`token_expiry`).

#### Scenario

So, how do you combine all of the above.

1. Authenticate `gcloud` with all your Google accounts

```sh
ACCOUNT="client1@gmail.com"
gcloud auth login ${ACCOUNT}

ACCOUNT="client2@gmail.com"
gcloud auth login ${ACCOUNT} # Last will be the `ACTIVE` account
```

2. Enumerate these

```sh
gcloud auth list
```

Yields:

```
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
        client1@gmail.com
*       client2@gmail.com # This is ACTIVE

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

3. Switch between users for `gcloud` commands

> **NOTE** This **doesn't** affect `kubectl`

**Either**

```sh
gcloud config set account client1@gmail.com
gcloud auth list
```

Yields:

```
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       client1@gmail.com # This is ACTIVE
        client2@gmail.com
```

**Or** you can explicitly add [`--account=${ACCOUNT}`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--account) to **any** `gcloud` command, e.g.:

```sh
# Explicitly unset your account
gcloud config unset account

# This will work and show projects accessible to client1
gcloud projects list --account=client1@gmail.com

# This will work and show projects accessible to client2
gcloud projects list --account=client2@gmail.com
```

2. Create `kubectl` contexts for any|all your Google accounts (via `gcloud`)

**Either**

```sh
ACCOUNT="client1@gmail.com"
PROJECT="..." # Project accessible to ${ACCOUNT}
gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${CLUSTER} \
--ACCOUNT=${ACCOUNT} \
--PROJECT=${PROJECT} \
...
```

**Or** equivalently using `kubectl config set-context` directly:

```sh
kubectl config set-context ${CONTEXT} \
--cluster=${CLUSTER} \
--user=${USER} \
```

But it avoids having to `gcloud config get-clusters`, `gcloud config get-users` etc.

> **NOTE** `gcloud containers clusters get-credentials` uses derived names for contexts and GKE uses derived names for clusters. **If you're confident** you can edit `kubectl` config directly (or using `kubectl config` commands) to rename these cluster, context and user references to suit your needs.

3. List `kubectl` contexts

```sh
kubectl config get-context
```

Yields:

```
CURRENT   NAME       CLUSTER    AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
*         client1    a-cluster  client1
          client2    b-cluster  client2
```

4. Switch between `kubectl` contexts (clusters*users)

> **NOTE** This **doesn't** affect `gcloud`

**Either**

```sh
kubectl config use-context ${CONTEXT}
```

*Or** you can explicitly add `--context` flag to **any** `kubectl` commands

```sh
# Explicitly unset default|current context
kubectl config unset current-context

# This will work and list deployments accessible to ${CONTEXT}
kubectl get deployments --context=${CONTEXT}
```

Comment: As always, thank you @DazWilkin for an **amazing** answer!

Comment: You're very welcome. There's lots of "hand-waving" by `gcloud` and `kubectl` to make this pain-free for the end-user which is good but it comes at the expense of it not being entirely obvious how it all works.

Comment: Just curious - once I use `gcloud container clusters get-credentials ...` to create the contexts (that I can just switch between via `kubectl`), I assume the `gcloud` account credentials (perhaps Open ID tokens stored somewhere on my file system?) will expire at some point and the `kubectl config use-context ...` commands will start failing?

Comment: No, they will be renewed on demand. See the part in the answer where I describe how `kubectl` uses `gcloud` to authenticate using `gcloud config config-helper --format=json`. `gcloud` will renew tokens when they expire.

Comment: so once you're logged into an account on a machine, you're always logged in? Isn't that a security risk? What if my laptop gets stolen?!

Comment: This is no longer related to your question and isn't programming related but relates to how the platform works. I encourage you to read up about Google Cloud Platform security and accounts stuff. It's well-documented online. Yes, while you're logged in another user with access to your unlocked machine, could access the platform using your credentials. As always, you should maintain good security protocols to protect your machine and the (many) credentials it will have on it. If you want you can `gcloud auth revoke ${ACCOUNT}`.